# Scipy and Skimage Install Issues

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, scikit-image

I am on a 64bit window, with Python 2.7. When I typed in "from scipy import signal" and "from skimage import filters", I got the following DLL and fail to import sigtools error messages, respectively (see below).

I uninstalled numpy, scipy, sckit-image, and Pillow, then reinstalled the followings. But the errors persist. Does anybody know how to fix it?

1) numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl 2) scikit_image-0.12.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl 3) scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl 4) Pillow-3.4.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Error messages start here:

```
from scipy import signal Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-c14ca79fb68c>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy import signal

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    from ._max_len_seq import max_len_seq

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

from skimage import filters Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-044505a8e654>", line 1, in <module>
    from skimage import filters

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .edges import (sobel, hsobel, vsobel, sobel_h, sobel_v,

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\filters\edges.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..restoration.uft import laplacian

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .deconvolution import wiener, unsupervised_wiener, richardson_lucy

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\restoration\deconvolution.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.signal import fftconvolve, convolve

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 284, in <module>
    from . import sigtools

ImportError: cannot import name sigtools
```

Comment: Hard to debug this. But i can promise you: use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and you will be ready within 10 minutes max.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whl` files from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

*Search your modules* and *download* them and then

```
pip install <drag your whl file here>
```